# Is there someway to optimize this code to run faster?

Tags: java, optimization, rainbowtable

I am writing a program to take an MD5 hash and run it against a dictionary.txt file. if I just run a word that is in the file it cracks it fast, but if I add a special character it takes about 10 minutes to crack. Is there some way to make it run faster?
If I run the MD5 hash of $hello (932d24e18f06b12e7a867425d51c909a) it takes about 10 minutes to crack.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cracker extends verify {

    private static String specialCharacters = "@#$%&";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> dictionaryWords = new LinkedList<>();
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data/dictionary.txt"));
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                dictionaryWords.add(s.next());
            }
            s.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the password MD5 hash to crack:");
        String md5target = s.nextLine();
        s.close();
        long startTime = new Date().getTime();
        boolean cracked = false;
        System.out.println("Trying to crack it with type 1 attack");
        for (String word : dictionaryWords) {
            //if (MD5.md5(word).equals(md5target)) {
            if (MD5.md5(word).equals(md5target))  { 
                System.out.println("Password is " + word);
                cracked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!cracked) {
            System.out.println("No matches in dictionary. Start looking for type 2 password");
            outer: for (String word : dictionaryWords) {
                List<String> combinationsForDictionaryWord = generateAllType2CombinationsForWord(word);
                for (String generatedWord : combinationsForDictionaryWord) {
                    if (MD5.md5(generatedWord).equals(md5target)) {
                        System.out.println("Password is " + generatedWord);
                        cracked = true;
                        break outer;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!cracked) {
                System.out.println("The password is not type 2 password. Not cracked");
            }
        }
        if (cracked) {
            System.out.println("Total time:" + (new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000.0 + " s");
        }
    }

    private static List<String> generateAllType2CombinationsForWord(String word) {
        List<String> combinations = new LinkedList<>();
        List<String> oneLetterCombinations = new LinkedList<>();
        // all combinations with 1 letter
        for (int i = 0; i <= word.length(); i++) {
            for (char ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++) {
                oneLetterCombinations.add(new StringBuffer(word).insert(i, ch).toString());
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < specialCharacters.length(); j++) {
                oneLetterCombinations.add(new StringBuffer(word).insert(i, specialCharacters.charAt(j)).toString());
            }
        }
        combinations.addAll(oneLetterCombinations);
        List<String> twoLetterCombinations = new LinkedList<>();
        // all combinations with two letters
        for (String sourceWord : oneLetterCombinations) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= sourceWord.length(); i++) {
                for (char ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++) {
                    twoLetterCombinations.add(new StringBuffer(sourceWord).insert(i, ch).toString());
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < specialCharacters.length(); j++) {
                    twoLetterCombinations
                            .add(new StringBuffer(sourceWord).insert(i, specialCharacters.charAt(j)).toString());
                }
            }
        }
        combinations.addAll(twoLetterCombinations);

        return combinations;
    }

}
'''
```

Comment: You can easily parallelize it.

Comment: You need a faster implementation. That is off topic here.

Comment: Change your list to a `HashSet` then instead of looping through your list you can just call `contains` to see if it exists.

Comment: That was my first thought too @locus2k but that would require to calculate all MD5 checksums a-priori. This would increase the start-up time but would also drastically improve lookup speed. The OP would then have a proper rainbow table for rainbow attacks.

Comment: Don't use `StringBuffer` - use `StringBuilder` instead. It'll rid the overhead of unnecessary synchronization.

Comment: Profile the code; FlightRecorder will surely help you, and then search an alternative to the bottleneck. If most of the time is contrived in a single class/method then parallelize using threads (looks like your code is easy to rewrite in the stream model so parallelizing it will be very easy). If not, then a finer analysis is required and out of scope for the moment.

Comment: As @JohannesKuhn mentioned you can parallize it `dictionaryWords.parallelStream().forEach()`

Comment: `List<String> dictionaryWords = Files.lines(Path.of("data/dictionary.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());`
and `dictionaryWords.parallelStream().filter(word -> MD5.md5(word).equals(md5target)).findAny();`

Comment: It would be much better to not collect a List from `generateAllType2CombinationsForWord` but return a `Stream<String>`..